# Java generic inference is too broad?

Tags: java, generics, recursion, lambda, type-inference

I have 2 classes:

```
class M {
    public <R, A, T extends A> A walk(BiFunction<Widget, Integer, Stream<R>> walker, BiFunction<A, Stream<R>, T> accF, A acc, int level) {
        return accF.apply(acc, walker.apply(this, level));
    }
}
```

and

```
class N extends M {

    public Stream<M> getChildren() {return Stream.of(new M()...);}

    @Override
    public <RR, A, T extends A> T walk(BiFunction<Widget, Integer, Stream<RR>> walker, BiFunction<A, Stream<RR>, T> accF, A acc, int level) {
        return accF.apply(accF.apply(acc, walker.apply(this, level)), getChildren().map(o -> o.walk(walker, accF, acc, level + 1)));
    }
}
```

However, the compiler says at `o.walk(walker, accF, acc, level + 1)` that `inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: T upper bounds: A, Object, RR`

Why so and how do I fix this?

Comment: Is this your way on how to make someones day miserable?

Comment: @MuratK. heheh :) well, maybe it looks a bit complex.. but that's just a recursive tree visitor.. and as for the type thing here, it's pretty usual in Scala programming.. not perceived as something off-world.. idk for Java though..

Comment: Can you make it compilable **except** for the actual error in quesiton? I.e. what are `Widget` and the `...` ?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the lambda syntax here but if I'm not mistaken the `map()` method should return a value of type `Stream<RR>` since that's how `accF` is defined. However, since you also pass `accF` to `o.walk()` you're trying to return a value of type `T` which doesn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

That's some really complex code and I don't have the time to really think about it, but since `getChildren()` returns any `M` and `N#walk` uses its own generic definitions the compiler knows that e.g. `A` could be a different type with different boundaries for the children and `walk`.

You might try to put the generic definitions at class level, e.g.

```
class M <R, A, T extends A> { 
  public  A walk(...) { ... }
}

class N <RR, A, T extends A> extends M< RR, A, T> { 
  public Stream<M<RR, A, T>> getChildren() {...}
  public  A walk(...) { ... }
}
```